# Как сделать правильно парсер?

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему: никак не работает парсинг с авторизацией. Посмотрел все видео, правда, их там не так много, ничего не помогает. Просто каждый раз отдает мне код страницы с авторизацией.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import fake_useragent

session = requests.Session()
link = 'https://moodle.asu.edu.ru/login/index.php'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': user.random
}

data = {
    "username": "//////",
    "password": "//////"
}
response = session.post(link, data=data, headers=headers)
profile_info = 'https://moodle.asu.edu.ru'
profile_response = session.get(profile_info)
print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если посмотреть на запросы (В Chrome F12 -> Вкладка Сеть) при входе, то можно увидеть что необходим ещё аргумент `logintoken` который каждое открытие страницы разный поэтому нужно его сначала получить, а уже потом делать запрос. Пример кода:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import fake_useragent
import re

session = requests.Session()
user = fake_useragent.FakeUserAgent()
link = 'https://moodle.asu.edu.ru/login/index.php'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': user.random
}

# Получаем logintoken
response = session.get(link)
soap = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
login_token = soap.find('input', {'name':"logintoken"})['value']

data = {
    "username": "////",
    "password": "////",
    "logintoken":login_token
}

response = session.post(link, data=data, headers=headers)
profile_info = 'https://moodle.asu.edu.ru'
profile_response = session.get(profile_info)
print(response.text)
```